# Is the base of a POSPACE also partially ordered?

Tags: general-topology

Given a POSPACE X are its bases also necessarily partially ordered?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_space

If not, given a partially ordered set as a base for a topological space Y what kind of space would Y be? Would Y necessarily be a POSPACE? Would all its other bases necessarily be partially ordered?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "the base" of a topological space? Any topology has many bases. And any basis is partially ordered by the subset relation, for example. I recommend you include more information about *why* you're asking this question, so people will be able to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to impart a topology to an (partial) order.
The simple ones are usually not Hausdorff.

Of note is the Scott topology for a dcpo,
A directed complete partial order.

Order and Topology, at.yorku.ca/t/a/i/c/05.htm.
An ordered topological space is a topological space (X,T) equipped
with a partial order <=. Usual compatibility conditions between the
topology and order include convexity (T has a basis of order-convex
sets) and the T_2-ordered property:  <=, ie { (x,y) | x <= y }, is
closed in XxX.

Since every topological space (X,T) can be considered as a trivially ordered space (X,T,=), the theory of ordered spaces includes the usual topological theory as a special case. Other important cases, each with its own techniques, include the totally ordered spaces and lattices.